# How to integrate logarithm and power functions?

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x) \ln(1+x) x^{a-1}\,dx, ~~a>0 $$
Any suggestion?

Comment: Maple does this in terms of the Lerch Phi.

Comment: You are supposed here to show your own efforts; explain what you tried and tell where you are stuck. Did you digest the answer to your previous question ? Did you understand how the work was done ?

Comment: @GEdgar. Just curious where  Lerch Phi would appear. What I got is an expansion in terms of polygamma's I was unable to simplify further to anything. Would you mind to send me Maple results by e-mail (my address is in my profile) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to repeat my analysis from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597965/how-to-integrate-logarithm-and-power-function); so you find the details there.

We have that
$$I= \int_{0}^{1}\!dx\,\ln(x) \ln(1+x) x^{a-1} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b} 
\int_{0}^{1}\!dx\,\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{b}{j} x^j x^{a-1} \biggl|_{b=0}
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}  \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{b}{j} \frac{1}{a+j}.$$

Now we need to find $\partial_{b} \binom{b}{j}|_{b=0}$. For that we note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \ln \binom{b}{j} = \psi(b+1) -\psi(1+b -j).$$
For $b\to0$, we have that $\binom{b}{j} = (-1)^{j+1} b/j$, we we need the term proportional to $b^{-1}$ of $\psi(b+1) - \psi(b+1 -j)$. We have that $\psi(b+1 -j) = -1/b +O(1)$ (for $j\in\mathbb{N}$) and $\psi(b+1)$ regular,  thus
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{b}} \binom{b}{j}\biggl|_{b=0} = \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}.$$

We obtain
$$I= \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j (j+a)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{1}{a} \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[  \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j} +\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+a} \right]. \tag{1}$$
The first sum gives $\ln 2$. In the second sum we split the even and odd part and obtain
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+a} =
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{a+ 2j} - \frac{1}{a+2j-1} \right)
= \frac12 \left[ \psi(1/2+a/2) -\psi(1+a/2) \right]. $$

So in total we have
$$I = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{1}{a} \left[ \ln 2  + \frac12 \psi(1/2+a/2) - \frac12 \psi(1+a/2) \right].$$

An alternative expression, following directly from (1), is given by
$$I = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j(j+a)^2}.$$

Comment: Pure beauty again !

Answer (score 0):

Requested Maple answer:
$$
\int_0^1 \log(x)\log(1+x)\,x^{a-1}\;dx = 
-{\frac {\Phi \left( -1,2,a \right) {a}^{2}+\ln  \left( 2
 \right) a+\Phi \left( -1,1,a \right) a-2\;}{{a}^{3}}}
$$
assuming $a>0$.  Here $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function
$$
\Phi \left( z,q,a \right) :=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {{z}^
{n}}{ \left( a+n \right) ^{q}}}
$$