# How can I show the following equation is true?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I was working on a problem and reduced it to showing  ‎‎
 $\psi(b-j)=-\frac{1}{b}+\psi(j+1)+O(b),$ 
where $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\psi(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\ln \Gamma(t)$. 
Your suggestion?

Comment: Post the original problem so people can see how you ended up with this equality.

Comment: please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597965/how-to-integrate-logarithm-and-power-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b\rightarrow 0$ you get with the [digamma reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula):
$$\psi(b-j) = \psi(j+1-b) + \pi \cot\Big((\pi(j+1-b)\Big)
=\psi(j+1-b) - \pi \cot(\pi b)$$
$$ \sim \psi(j+1) -\psi'(j+1)b + O(b^2)
- \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{3}b + O(b^2)$$
$$\sim - \frac{1}{b} +  \psi(j+1) + O(b)$$